# Running in issues after running Spark/scala job with single case id

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My Spark/Scala code was running well enough while for a single "CASE ID", by filtering in the queries used in the code.

After that, I tried to run the code against an entire dataset, but it was stopping at `ds.map(...)` function as shown in below piece of code.

It's still running fine when I run it on a small amount of data (but still failing when run on 1000 rows of data).

```
val df = sparkSessionContext.sql(s"select * from $persistDb.cdf_cpm_interim2")

val ds = df.as[MyData]

ds
  .map(a => func1(a))
  .write
  .mode("overwrite")
  .option("header", "true")
  .parquet(s"${Interimpath}/cdf_cpm_interim3")

sparkSessionContext.sql(s"REFRESH TABLE $persistDb.cdf_cpm_interim3")
```

Volume of data in `cdf_cpm_interim2`: 312,597,407

Error message in the log is as below:

> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 66.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 66.0 (TID 2548, dbslp1219.uhc.com, executor 3): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:264)

Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `DataFrame` API instead of Datasets?

Furthermore, the problem could also depend by what the function `func1` is doing...

IMHO, if you're loading a considerable amount of data, you should avoid to do strange things like `transform data-structures` using map functions, since Spark will load all of your data in the driver, and obviously if the driver does not have enough memory, it will easily go in `OutOfMemory`.

You should achieve your goal by taking advantage of workers.